Local structure at ramification points of a morphism of smooth curves
Let $f:C \longrightarrow D$ be a morphism of smooth curves, simply branched and of degree $k$. We know that if $f$ is étale at $q \in C$ and $p=f(q) \in D$, then for $t$ a regular parameter in $\mathcal{O}_{D,f(q)}$, we have the isomorphism
$$
\widehat{\mathcal{O}}_{C,q} \simeq \widehat{\mathcal{O}}_{D, f(q)}\simeq \mathbb{C} [[t]] 
$$
Now, consider a ramification point $\tilde{q}$ such that
$p=f(\tilde{q})$ for some $p$ in the branch locus of $f$.

Why can we assert that for $t$ a regular parameter in $\mathcal{O}_{D,f(\tilde{q})}$, we have the isomorphism

$$
\widehat{\mathcal{O}}_{C, \tilde{q}} \simeq \widehat{\mathcal{O}}_{D, f(\tilde{q})}[\sqrt{t}] \simeq \mathbb{C} [[ \sqrt{t} ]]?
$$

Why can we choose a square root $\sqrt{t} \in \mathcal{O}_{C,\tilde{q}}$? What does it mean for the $\sqrt{t}$ to belong to $\mathcal{O}_{C,\tilde{q}}$?

I am trying to better understand the local structure around ramification points and how the formalization with $\sqrt{t}$ arises in this context. What would be the geometric or algebraic intuition behind this choice?

Do you mean to assume that the ramification index of $f$ at $\tilde{q}$ is $2$?

Yes, f is simply branched of degree d over the yours ramifications
points, i.e., each ramification index is 2 and there is at most one ramification point in every fiber.

Choose a local parameter $s \in \mathcal{O}_{C,q}$, so that $\hat{\mathcal{O}}_{C,q} \cong \mathbb C [[s]]$. The map $f$ induces a morphism of rings
$$\mathbb C[[s] = \hat{\mathcal O}_{C,q} \xrightarrow{\varphi} \hat{\mathcal O}_{D,p} = \mathbb C[[t]],$$
and by definition of the ramification index,
$$\varphi(s) = t^2(a_0 + a_1t + a_2t^2 + \dotsb) = a_0 t^2 (1 + b_1t + b_2t^2 + \dotsb),$$
with $a_0 \neq 0$. Remember from your analysis classes the binomial series, which gives us a power series formula for the square root
$$\sqrt{1+x} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \binom{\frac 1 2}{k} x^k.$$
Setting $x = b_1t + b_2t^2 + \dotsb$, you get a power series expansion for $v = \sqrt{1+b_1t + \dotsb}$. Now choose a square root $\sqrt{a_0}$, and set
$$\tilde t = \sqrt{a_0} v t.$$
Since $v$ is a unit and $\sqrt{a_0}\neq 0$, this is another coordinate, i.e. $\mathbb C[[t]] = \mathbb C[[\tilde t]]$. By construction we have
$$\varphi(s) = \tilde t^2.$$
This justifies the notation $s = \sqrt{\tilde t}$, or
$$\hat {\mathcal O}_{C,q} = \hat{\mathcal O}_{D,p}[\sqrt{\tilde t}].$$

This means that a ramification of index $2$ looks analytically just like
$$\mathbb C \to \mathbb C, z \mapsto z^2.$$

Exercise. Use the same argument to show that a ramification of index $d$ looks analytically like
$$\mathbb C \to \mathbb C, z \mapsto z^d.$$
